# NodeJS How to correctly implement listeners for SIGINT / SIGTERM signals to dispose resources?

Tags: node.js

I am newbie trying to learn nodejs, and struggling to understand how to correctly override SIGINT/SIGTERM handlers for safe disposal of resources in a forked child process.

- If I override just SIGINT then I have to issue CTRL-C again in the terminal to terminate.
- If I override just SIGTERM then when a SIGINT is issued the process exits, however the custom SIGTERM handler is NOT triggered.

The *Nodejs* [documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_signal_events) states that:

> 'SIGTERM' and 'SIGINT' have default handlers on non-Windows platforms that reset the terminal mode before exiting with code 128 + signal number. If one of these signals has a listener installed, its default behavior will be removed (Node.js will no longer exit).

It looks as though that if a listener is implemented for either SIGINT or SIGTERM then both the default handlers are removed.

How do I mimic the default behaviour for SIGINT with the added functionality of triggering SIGTERM to dispose of resources?

Currently, I have:

```
/**
 * Signal handlers 
 */
process.on('SIGTERM', (signal, code) => {
  signalExit(code, me);
});

process.on('SIGINT', (signal, code) => {
  signalExit(code, me);
});


/**
 * Reset the terminal, dispose of resources and exit with code 128+exitCode
 * @param {number} exitCode - Exit code
 * @param {Process} me - Process resource manager 
 */
function signalExit(exitCode, me) {
    process.stdout.write('\x1Bc');
    dispose(me);
    process.exit(128 + exitCode);
}
```

This does what I want in that both SIGINT and SIGTERM dispose of resources while exiting the process.

However, I am not sure about the following:

1. What should the exit code be if I caught an exception raised by the dispose function in *signalExit*?
2. What should be the behaviour / exit code for SIGINT and SIGTERM on Windows platform?